# read xlsx files with dynamic datetime values at the end of the file name

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I have daily files I want to read into sql server using python and want to know the syntax that would work to dynamically read the file names. the file names are all "activity_*DATE*.xlsx" where date is formatted like `yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss`. Any ideas? I have tried strftime etc.

Comment: Try using `glob.glob('activity_*.xlsx')`

Comment: i want to run this once a week for the files for the past week. should have added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
import os
import datetime

filenames = os.listdir()
for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'): # only grab Excel files
        date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_filename, "activity_%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%S.xlsx")
        print(date_object)
```

Where the important parts to parsing the times are explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Perhaps a more clear example would be:

```
my_filename = "activity_2019_05_13_11_21_30.xlsx"
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_filename, "activity_%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%S.xlsx")
print(date_object)
```

Results in

> 2019-05-13 11:21:30

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob('activity*.xlsx')], ignore_index = True)
```

You can try any of the solution you see fit.

Comment: @Reedinationer Yes, Modified it as suggested